# Xcode 8 Object Library stopped working

Tags: button, label, xcode8

I was working with base64 which kept giving errors in Swift3, and now the object library has stopped working.  I can't drag and drop buttons, or anything else onto a view.

I have tried product clean, turned Xcode on and off, turned the computer on and off.  Still not working.

Also, my touch pad will right click on other items, such as the info.plist. But, it will not right click on the object library items, such as button, label, and textfield.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works now. I tried several things, and found how to get the plus sign, drop indicator to work.